# Typescript - type 'false' is not assignable to type 'true'

Tags: angular, typescript

I am learning angular 2, and in this example where I set the variable for isLoading to true, and then change it to false, once I fetch the data I need, I get the error:

> Typescript - type 'false' is not assignable to type 'true'

This is the code:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    isLoading: true;

    constructor(private _articleService: ArticleService, private _postService: PostService){}

    ngOnInit(){
      this.articles = this._articleService.getArticles();
      this._postService.getPosts()
        .subscribe(posts => {
          this.isLoading = false;
          console.log(posts[0].title);
        });
    }
```

Comment: `isLoading: true;` -> `isLoading = true;`

Comment: `isLoading: boolean;`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Not required to define the type of variable at a time, but you should set to find bugs during development. In addition editor before know to complete the code thus he knows the type of the variable.

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
isLoading : boolean =  true;

constructor(private _articleService: ArticleService, private _postService: PostService){}

ngOnInit(){
  this.articles = this._articleService.getArticles();
  this._postService.getPosts()
    .subscribe(posts => {
      this.isLoading = false;
      console.log(posts[0].title);
    });
}
```

Comment: This is actually not necessary as the type `boolean` will be implied when declaring a variable and assigning it `true` or `false`. As in, simply writing `isLoading = true` will do the same thing as `isLoading: boolean = true`

Answer (score 19):

`isLoading: true;` means that the only value you can assign to `isLoading` is the value `true`. You want `isLoading: boolean`.

Comment: But how will I check it in my template if the data is loaded if I set it only to ```boolean```? I need false and true to do this.

Comment: @Leff `isLoading: boolean;` is equivalent to saying `isLoading: boolean = null;` null is falsy, so it's effectively defaulting `isLoading` to false. Your template should not complain.

Comment: @leff @Leff tslint warned me about `no-inferrable-types` so I changed `protected someProperty: boolean = false` to `protected someProperty: false` but now my application won't compile with `error TS2322: Type 'true' is not assignable to type 'false'`... what in the world? Any suggestions on how to appease both of these strictures?

Answer (score 11):

Based on suggestions from comments and the answer from @Louis, this was the right syntax to fix it:

```
isLoading: boolean = true;
```